# Database for cross platform mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, sql, database, rest

I'm currently creating an app, initially on Android and once completed also for IOS.

I need a database which all users will be able to access, i.e. if an Android user updates their location another user on Android or IOS will be able to view the change.

I've only ever had experience with the built in sqllite database for Android, so this is completely new to me!

I've been trying to research this for a while now, and I'm struggling to find a definitive answer.
From what I understand I could get web hosting and create a resful front end which would allow me to access the database on the hosted server, and then I would be able to use the restful api in my Native mobile apps and receive data back, by the looks of things potentially in a JSON format?
Is this correct?

Also on the server I will have an XMPP server running so that I can use chat functionality, would it be possible for the XMPP server to access the database as well?

Finally, if I am on the right lines, could anyone point me to potential solutions for databases/hosting or guides? And if I am not on the right lines, could someone tell me where I am going wrong!

Thanks for any help!
Matt

Comment: What you probably are looking for is this https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html. There is something called push messaging service where in you can push notifications and messages (in case of chats) to the android user and you may have to use the service Google Could for this. Similar thing should exist for iOS as well i am not sure but it seems this is the more appropriate way to achieve your task.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think this is really what I'm looking for.. the users will need to interact with other users data - like facebook - not just recieve messages when something changes.

Comment: Also, I already have the XMPP server working with aSmack running on the Android devices.

Comment: In that case the approach that you have mentioned in your question seems to be the right way ahead. It should work for you if implemented successfully. I will not be able to suggest solutions for the database or hosting services or guides, as i do not have idea on that. Just out of curiosity, are you using php on the server side in order to interact with the database and manage the request/response of your android users?